# The bootstrap.js file - are these a unique type of server-side include? How should these files be implemented?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rubygems

In the bootstrap sass download ( https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/archive/v3.1.1.tar.gz ) there is a strange bootstrap.js file with all of these lines here commented out, like so:

```
//= require bootstrap/affix
//= require bootstrap/alert
//= require bootstrap/button
//= require bootstrap/carousel
//= require bootstrap/collapse
//= require bootstrap/dropdown
//= require bootstrap/tab
//= require bootstrap/transition
//= require bootstrap/scrollspy
//= require bootstrap/modal
//= require bootstrap/tooltip
//= require bootstrap/popover
```

These correspond to the folder below that has the js files named by each "require" line.

**Are these some sort of special server side include system for javascript?**

While we are on the subject, what is the best practice for including these files in a page? 1 by 1 as they are needed (more requests?) or simply pasting them into a master file as needed (more work indeed, and subject to change, more stuff to track).

Perhaps there is something I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

These JS files are intended to be loaded/compiled by [Sprockets](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets).

If you are not using Rails, look at a solution for sinatra: https://gist.github.com/datenimperator/3668587